# Sorting an Arraylist of strings on a portion of each string, delimited by a character

Tags: c#, string, sorting, arraylist

I'm trying to sort an `ArrayList` of `string`s (not in `int`).

Given: 
f.e.

```
[0] 23,24
[1] 12,33
[2] 37,11
```

`Arraylist.Sort` should give back (sorted by the last number ascending):

```
[0] 37,11
[1] 23,24
[2] 12,33
```

Having this so far:

```
public class Point
{
    public int i, j;

    public Point(int i, int j)
    {this.i = i; this.j = j;}

    public string ToString()
    {return i + "," + j;}
}

public class SList
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ArrayList Slist = new ArrayList();
        Random Generate = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Point p = new Point(Generate.Next(40), Generate.Next(40));
            Slist.Add(p.ToString());
        }
        Slist.Sort();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far to accomplish this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using the non-generic `ArrayList` instead of the generic `List<T>`?

Comment: You haven't specified what is expected sorting

Comment: you want to sort using dictionary order (x before y) right? Why not make your `Point` class `IComparable` and/or use one of the obvious [Array.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort(v=vs.110).aspx) overloads?

Comment: How to do this with an `IComparable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if you have an array of strings or if they are split already, but you can create a custom comparer and do something like this perhaps. Make clearer what you want so that people can help you better.

```
    public class MyCustomComparer : IComparer<string>
    {
        public int Compare(string x, string y)
        {
            var xIntValues = x.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
            var yIntValues = y.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(int.Parse).ToArray();

            for(var i = 0; i < Math.Min(xIntValues.Count(), yIntValues.Count()); ++i)
                if (xIntValues[i] != yIntValues[i])
                    return xIntValues[i] - yIntValues[i];
            return xIntValues.Count() - yIntValues.Count();
        }
    }
```

Then use it like this where your array elements contain strings like `"37, 11"`

```
    Array.Sort(myArray, MyCustomComparer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort of odd to be using an `ArrayList` after c# 1.0, but if you have one for legacy reasons, you can create your own non-generic custom comparer, like so:

```
public class CustomComparer : IComparer<string>, IComparer {

    #region IComparer<string> Members

    int? ExtractNumber(string str)
    {
        int index = str.LastIndexOf(',');
        if (index < 0)
            return null;
        var subStr = str.Substring(index+1);
        int result;
        if (int.TryParse(subStr, out result))
            return result;
        return null;
    }

    // Return x - y
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
#if false
        Given: f.e.
        [0] 23,24
        [1] 12,33
        [2] 37,11
        Arraylist.Sort should give back (sorted by the last number ascending):
        [0] 37,11
        [1] 23,24
        [2] 12,33
#endif
        var xVal = ExtractNumber(x);
        var yVal = ExtractNumber(y);
        if (!xVal.HasValue && !yVal.HasValue)
            return x.CompareTo(y);
        else if (!xVal.HasValue)
            return 1;
        else if (!yVal.HasValue)
            return -1;
        int cmp = xVal.Value.CompareTo(yVal.Value);
        if (cmp != 0)
            return cmp;
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }

    #endregion

    #region IComparer Members

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return 0;
        string xStr = x as string;
        string yStr = y as string;
        if (xStr == null && yStr == null)
            return 0;  // NO IDEA
        else if (xStr == null)
            return 1;
        else if (yStr == null)
            return -1;
        else return Compare(xStr, yStr);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code implements `IComparable` on your class. It sorts on `y` in ascending order:

```
public class Point : IComparable<Point>
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public string ToString()
    {
        return x + "," + y;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Point other)
    {
         return this.y.CompareTo(other.y);
    }

}
```

You can now use `ArrayList.Sort()` to achieve the order you need.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be by stepping away from your non-generic list:

```
var sortedList = list.Cast<string>().OrderBy(x => x.Split(',')[1]);
```

The code is self-explanatory.

Using this as input:

```
var list = new ArrayList();
list.Add("23,24");
list.Add("12,33");
list.Add("37,11");
```

Yields this as output:

> 37,11
>   23,24
>   12,33